# Over writing an array and placing a zero back in its place

Tags: c#

I'm doing some school work and would just like to be pointed in the right direction. I am creating a Hotel project which books people in and also books them out when leaving. I'm struggling on a certain part which asks which room you need vacating and then puts a 0 into this position in the array. I am not going to beat around the bush i don't know where to start. This is my code so far.

```
using System;

namespace Task7_2
{


    class Motel
    {
        int[] rooms;
        const int MAX = 21;
        int roomNumber, guests, vacate;

        static void Main()
        {
            Motel BatesMotel = new Motel();
            BatesMotel.runMotel();
            BatesMotel.showAllRooms();



        }
        //*******************************************************
        public Motel()
        {
            rooms = new int[MAX + 1];        // allow rooms from 1 to MAX
        }
        //******************************************************
        public void runMotel()
        {
            string choice = "";
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("The Bates Motel");
                Console.WriteLine("===============");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Book a room");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Vacate a room");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Display ALL Room Details");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Vacate ALL rooms");
                Console.WriteLine("5. Quit");
                Console.Write("Enter your choice : ");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
                if (choice == "1")
                {
                    bookRoom();
                }
                else if (choice == "3")
                {

                    showAllRooms();
                }
                else if (choice == "2")
                {
                    vacateOneRoom();
                }
            }
            while (choice != "5");
        }
        //*******************************************************
        public void bookRoom()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\nThe Bates Motel");
            Console.WriteLine("===============");
            Console.WriteLine("Book a room");
            Console.Write("Enter the room number : ");
            roomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("How many guests : ");
            guests = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            rooms[roomNumber] = guests;     // make the booking
            Console.WriteLine("Room " + roomNumber + " booked for " + guests + " people");

        }
        //*******************************************************
        public void showAllRooms()
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Room " + (i )+"\t\t\t" + rooms[i] + " guests \n" );
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        public void vacateOneRoom()
        {
              Console.WriteLine("Which room is being vacated");


              Console.ReadLine();
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the code. :)

Comment: Didn't get your code - can you edit your question to include it?

Comment: @Candide: Not only that - many hotels have considerably less than 100 rooms per level, but number their rooms according to the level, like 100 * level + room-number.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<int> myList= new List<int>();

int num = 22;
myList.Add(num);
myList.Remove(num); //removes matching item

myList.Add(33);
myList.RemoveAt(0); //removes at array index
```

Comment: Just code for copy and pasting without any explanation may help the current asker with exactly this problem, but neither does it really help them with future similar problems, nor does it help any other visitors with related problems.

Comment: This code removes items from a list - the OP instead requests that an item can be set to 0 to indicate that the room is free.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool[] barray = new bool[number_of_rooms];
```

When someone booked a particular room then

```
barray[room_number]=true;
```

When someone vacate a particular room then

```
barray[room_number]=false;
```

checking

```
for(int i=0;i<barray.lenght;i++)
{
if(barray[i]==true)
Console.WriteLine("Room number"+300+i+"is not free");
else
Console.WriteLine("Room number"+300+i+"is free");
}
```

example output:::

Room number 300 is not free
Room number 301 is not free
Room number 302 is free
Room number 303 is not free
Room number 304 is free